# External CD/DVD drive on 27" iMac

Tags: imac, external-drive

I recently acquired (OK bought) a new 27" iMac and have an issue that I'm trying to get around...  With where the iMac is sitting on my desk, I don't have access to the CD/DVD drive.  The good news is that I don't need access very often, but when I do, I don't want to be moving the $2K screen around, I really don't want to even touch it.

Can I add an external drive to use with the iMac?  I know they sell a "super drive" for the MacBook air.  What about a Blu-Ray drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes you can.  Quick search on newegg resulted in:

[PLEXTOR Black 6X BD-ROM 16X DVD-ROM 48X CD-ROM USB External BD Combo Super Multi Drive Model PX-B310U](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827249040&cm_re=usb_blue_ray-_-27-249-040-_-Product)

$139 at time of writing.

Not sure if Apple's software supports playing Blue Ray discs yet, though.  I've not messed with it yet.